# How do I get gCentroid to work at the pole?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, centroid

I am struggling with *gCentroid*, because it doesn't seem -- to me -- to give the 'right' answer near a pole of the Earth.

For instance:

```
library(rgeos)

gCentroid(SpatialPoints(coords=data.frame(longitude=c(-135,-45,45,135),latitute=c(80,80,80,80)),proj4string = CRS('EPSG:4326')))
```

does not give me the North Pole, it gives:

```
> SpatialPoints: 
>   x  y 
> 1 0 80 
> Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

How do I get *gCentroid* to work on the surface of the Earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GEOS library is limited to planar geometry operations; this can bring issues in edge cases / the poles being a notorious example.

For the centroid via GEOS to work as intended you need to transform your coordinates from WGS84 to a coordinate reference system appropriate to polar regions; for Arctic regions I suggest [EPSG:3995](https://epsg.io/3995).

```
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(rgeos)

points_sp <- SpatialPoints(coords=data.frame(longitude=c(-135,-45,45,135),latitute=c(80,80,80,80)),proj4string = CRS('EPSG:4326'))

points_updated <- points_sp %>% 
  spTransform(CRS("EPSG:3995")) # a projected CRS apropriate for Arctic regions
  
centroid <- gCentroid(points_updated) %>% 
  spTransform(CRS("EPSG:4326")) # back to safety of WGS84!

centroid # looks better now...
# SpatialPoints:
#  x  y
# 1 0 90
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Also note that your workflow - while not wrong in principle - is a bit dated, and the `{rgeos}` package is approaching its end of life.

It may be good time to give a strong consideration to `{sf}` package, which is newer, actively developed and can, via interface to s2 library from Google, handle spherical geometry operations.

For an example of `{sf}` based workflow consider this code; the result (centroid = North Pole) is equivalent to the sp / rgeos one.

```
library(sf)

points_sf <- points_sp %>% # declared earlier
  st_as_sf()


centroid_sf <- points_sf %>% 
  st_union() %>%  # unite featrues / from 4 points >> 1 multipoint
  st_centroid()

centroid_sf # the North Pole in a slightly different (sf vs sp) format
# Geometry set for 1 feature 
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 90 xmax: 0 ymax: 90
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84 (with axis order normalized for visualization)
# POINT (0 90)
```

Comment: Thank you. So how would you go about computing a centroid with sf? Sorry that this digresses from the original question...

Comment: I have edited the answer to show a possible sf based workflow; the only tricky part is the need to unite the 4 source points to single multipoint geometry - othervise the `sf::st_centroid()` would be applied *per feature* = you would get your points back unchanged, as the centroid of a point is the point itself